# How do I subscribe a web socket end point in kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, websocket

I create my spring boot web socket according to the [doc](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) and how can I subscribe this end point in kotlin.

```
@MessageMapping("/chat")
public void chatNotice() {
    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/chat");
}
```

Is there a way to subscribe like in js

```
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
      console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
      stompClient.subscribe('/topic/chat', function (greeting) {
        console.log(greeting);
      });
    });
```

If I use okhttp,

```
override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket?, text: String?) {
    output("Receiving : " + text!!)
}
```

but how can I subscribe an end point?